Covering missing derivations in Bengio RNN exploding gradient/output paper
While I have no doubts about the soundness of its conclusions given that it is very well-known, I have been looking through the classic paper on RNNs which is used to substantiate the claims that gradients 1) may vanish for small enough spectral norm of the recurrent weights $\mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{rec}}$ and 2) may explode for large enough values. (I also wanted to check the claim that 3) in case of ReLU activation that we would see exploding outputs in some cases.)
The authors prove (1) using a reparameterization which I checked preserves both losses and gradients for the weights identically, so that I agree it leaves the problem identical; then proved briefly that small enough values for $||\mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{rec}}||$ will definitely cause vanishing in training the reparameterized problem.
But they only indicated that inverting the conditions for vanishing gradient is necessary (by contrapositive) for gradient explosion.
Looking at the paper - is there a reasonable proof, maybe using some matrix norms for inverses or other technique to try to invert the inequality, that gets more explicit about sufficiency for gradient explosion? I suspect if I had that I could also show how ReLU might lead to explosions since if you can neglect other terms it's a similar case since it's another matrix power multiplication after that.
The claims I'm verifying come up, for instance, in the old Geron book "Hands-On Machine Learning," and some NLP courses, but this is never actually shown.
